# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\ln(x^2 - 1)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

How can I show that

$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \ln(x^2 - 1) = \infty$$

My approach would be to compute the derivative and simply show that the derivative is always positive for large inputs of type $x^2 - 1$, so log is an increasing function and goes to infinity as $x^2 -1$ goes to infinity.

Another approach seems to get me into some trouble, i.e. trying to using log rules:

$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \ln(x^2 - 1)$$

$$ = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \ln( (x-1) \cdot (x+1))$$

$$ = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \ln(x-1) + \ln(x+1),$$

which now leaves me stuck and can't evaluate these limits, as x goes to negative infinity.  How could I resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: A reputable user like yourself should know to precede upright functions with \  and to use `\cdot` instead of `*`…

Comment: as your function is even in nature it will have same limit for $\pm\infty$

Answer (score 1):

It is known that $\lim_{y \to +\infty} \ln y=+\infty$. On the other hand $y=x^2-1 \to +\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

you must Show that $\ln(x^2-1)>M$ for $x<-\sqrt{e^M+1}$ and $M>0$

Answer (score 0):

For $x$ large (opposite direction), $\ln(x^{2}-1)\geq\ln(x^{2}-(-x))=\ln(-x)+\ln(-x-1)\geq\ln(-x)\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right -- we only have that $\ln(AB) = \ln(A) + \ln(B)$ for $A, B > 0$, which does throw a small wrench in your approach.

However, since $x^2 = |x|^2$, we have

$$\ln(x^2 - 1) = \ln(|x|^2 - 1) = \ln\big((|x| - 1)(|x| + 1)\big) = \ln(|x| - 1) + \ln(|x| + 1)$$

for $|x| > 1$, and in particular, as $x \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^2=(-x)^2= f(-x)$ is even.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} x^2 = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x^2$

Let $y:= x^2-1>0.$

Consider:

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \log (y) =\infty.$